# How to render emission materials in 3D viewport?

Tags: rendering, materials, emission

I'm a omplete beginner in blender

I tried to do a 'low poly' volcano. Everything went well, for the lava I have a material, set on 'emission', that emits a glowing red.

However, I can't make it appear in the 3D viewport. It seems like I have a 'viewport display' window, which is set to white, but I don't want to set an other color and would like my material, set on emission, red,  to show on the viewport.

It happens that when I export the volcano on fbx, the material isn't shown either, and I don't manage to see a solution. Has someone ever encountered this problem ?

Comment: Please post some pictures of your material nodes, and what it looks like in the viewport,

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the rendering view and object view?

If so then your emission is too powerful that it becomes white. Reduce its strength.

For the fbx the materials are directly tied to the render engine so exporting it results just the model, there is no solution so far.

[image]